# Proving function is Schwartz

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, schwartz-space

I want to prove that $f(t)=e^{-t^2C\pi}$ is Schwartz. I tried computing derivatives and showing that for all $n,k\in \mathbb{N}_0$
$$\lim_{t\to \infty}t^{k}f^{(n)}(t)=0$$
but it gets messy pretty fast. Is there another way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is easy to see that $f^{(n)}(t)=P_n(t)\,e^{-C\pi t^2}$, where $P_n$ is a polynomial of degree $n$. Now you have to prove that $\lim_{t\to\infty}t^ke^{-C\pi t^2}=0$ for all $k\in\mathbb N$.

Comment: So we wish to prove that the limit goes to zero to guarantee that the function does not go off to infinity? and hence is bounded since the function is continuous for all of $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: It would be enough to show they are bounded.